# Get Custom fields from PAGE in POSTs

Tags: php, wordpress

I've a simple problem but i don't know how fix.

I create custom fields from my web, i use this to generate something style in the header.

The header its same in **example.com/taxonomy** and **example.com/taxonomy/post_type**

I've create something like this:

**Inputs:**

```
    function agregar_campos() {
      add_meta_box('input_serie','Información de Nueva Serie','input_serie','page','normal','high');
      add_meta_box('input_episodios','Información de Nuevos Episodios','input_episodios','episodio','normal','high');
}
function input_serie() {
 global $wpdb, $post;
// Color
$value  = (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'color', true));
echo '<label for="color">Color Hexadecimal:</label>
<input type="text" name="color" id="color" value="'.htmlspecialchars($value).'" placeholder="Color Hexadecimal de la serie" style="width: 100%;" />';
 // Nav
$value  = (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'nav', true));
echo '<label for="nav">Nav de la Serie:</label>
<input type="text" name="nav" id="nav" value="'.htmlspecialchars($value).'" placeholder="URL DIRECTA Nav de Serie: img/nav/_nombre_serie.jpg" style="width: 100%;" />';

function input_episodios() {
global $wpdb, $post;
// Número de Temporada
$value  = (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'numerotemporada', true));
echo '<label for="numerotemporada">N&uacute;mero de Temporada:</label>
<input type="text" name="numerotemporada" id="numerotemporada" value="'.htmlspecialchars($value).'" placeholder="Ingresa el Número de la Temporada" style="width: 100%;" />';
```

**Page (taxonomy):**

```
$nav = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'nav',true);
$cover = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cover',true);
<header id="head" style="background: url('http://cdn.enlatino.net/img/covers/<?php echo $cover; ?>') top center no-repeat, <?php echo $color;?>; z-index:1;">
```

This work fine, but in **/taxonomy/post_type** doesn't work!

2 pictures for you understandme:

http://prntscr.com/62hma5

http://prntscr.com/62hmhs

How can fix this? I've same get_post_meta in the two templates.

Thanks so much!!

Comment: you have a proble from style path check your css file path

Comment: There isn't a file path problem!
Look: http://prntscr.com/62hzb7
In meta_key 'nav' i put the file name with extension (image.jpg) to complete the URL (http://www.example.com/img/covers/image.jpg), but this no work, no get the custom field value :/